# The regularity of Levy process

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

There is a property for continuous Markov process that  each point $y$  in its state space is hit with positive probability one starting from any interior point $x$.

This property is called the regularity of continuous Markov process. For example, $X_{t}$ is the 1-dimensional brownian motion. The state space is $(-\infty, +\infty)$.
I found this concept from  the paper: on increasing continuous Markov processes by E.CINLAR. Maybe there is another name from standard text book.

My question is as follows. Suppose $X_{t}$ is a Levy process which is not a pure jump process. This  means $\sigma\neq 0 $ in its generating triplet $(\sigma, \gamma, \nu）$. Is $X_{t}$ regular?

Any references are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is to let $X_t$ be Brownian motion with drift. Start at any point $x$ and suppose the drift is negative.
Let $N_y$ be the event that $y$ is never hit, i.e., $N_y=\{(\forall t)\, X_t < y\}$.
With probability one there will be some positive value that is not hit; see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169548/max-of-brownian-motion-with-drift-is-finite-almost-surely).
So
$$
\mathbb P (\cup_{y\in\mathbb N}\, N_y) = 1.
$$
Therefore
$$
\exists y\in\mathbb N\qquad \mathbb P(N_y)>0,
$$
and such a $y$ is a counterexample to regularity.

Comment: Thanks your answer. It's very helpful. Maybe the way I asked  or that paper is wrong. It's worthwhile to checking it carefully.

Comment: I do not know where in the paper you found the statement "hit with probability one". I can only find "hit with positive probability".

Comment: (I answered the probability-one version of the question, version number 1)